# Force URL lowercase PHP/htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have the following that I'd like to make all lowercase...

```
echo '<a href="/people/' . $row["Location_County"] . '/' . $row["First_Name"] . '-' . $row["Surname"] . '/' . $row["ID"] . '">View Profile</a>';
```

Each county is capitalised as well as their names, is their a way I can force this all lowercase? Is it poeeible to do it with htaccess or can I do this using PHP?

Comment: What is your current .htaccess? You just posted PHP code, so wondering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do that manually using [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower):

```
echo '<a href="/people/' . strtolower($row["Location_County"]) . '/' . strtolower($row["First_Name"]) . '-' . strtolower($row["Surname"]) . '/' . $row["ID"] . '">View Profile</a>';
```

And this issue has **nothing** to do with `mod_rewrite` at all, because it works **before** the request is processed.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
strtolower($yourString);
```

And read documentation before asking question, please. It covers 99% of basic questions.

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Example :

> echo strtolower("your String");

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="/people/' . strtolower($row["Location_County"]) . '/' . strtolower($row["First_Name"]) . '-' . strtolower($row["Surname"]) . '/' . $row["ID"] . '">View Profile</a>';
```

Use strtolower(); function

Here is the Strlower() function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php 
And if you want you can make uppercase too http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

You should really look in to these on http://php.net/ they are basic functions.